# UIWebView ShouldStartLoadWithRequest can't goBack

Tags: ios, uiwebview, history

I'm working with `UIWebView`. And I added this method to my `UIViewController`.

It seemed working well, but after moving two steps with links,

it just calls the last page and the before last page each other with `[myWebView goBack]`,

and `[myWebView canGoForward]` is false all the time.

Can I get any help?

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj;

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward ||
        navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ||
        navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload) {

        NSURL *URL = [request URL];
        NSLog(@"url: %@", URL);
        if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"]) {
            requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[URL absoluteString]]];
            [requestObj addValue:@"myKey" forHTTPHeaderField:@"myHeader"];
            [_web_view loadRequest:requestObj];
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

add: I can't put the value in 'User-Agent'. That's why I'm doing this.

Comment: But why you load the same request when webview already is loading it?

Comment: Sorry for the log. I was frustrating.

Comment: You want to put your own custom headers to request, you should check if they are already in request. http://www.nomadplanet.fr/2010/09/custom-http-headers-for-every-request-made-in-uiwebviews/

Comment: I've got buttons on app to load specific pages and navigation buttons to access to the history. What I have to do is sending custom header every time the web page is loading. I connected the buttons' action with a method but have no idea with other conditions.

Comment: Inject IOS, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.

The problem was , i was calling loadRequest again after clicking on back button.
Instead if u call goBack , goForward , webview properly maintains its stack and canGoback and cangoforward flags.

I hope that will help.